# Nginx Reverse Proxy 405 PUT Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, put, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-405

I'm getting a 405 response when I try to request to my Tomcat server through     an Nginx reverse proxy.

If I request directly to the tomcat server it works successfully from Chrome or Firefox. But if I request to Nginx Proxy I get a 405 from Chrome, but works from Firefox.

I've been testing with different configuration in my nginx.conf under 
    location/foo/ { ... }

I've tried:

```
error_page 405 =200 $uri;
```

Also

```
 add_header "Allow" "GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" always;`

location / {
    dav_methods PUT DELETE;
    proxy_pass http://csprocure;
}
```

My nginx.conf for redirections is as follows:

```
upstream serverS {
   server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name $hostname;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    error_log   /dev/stdout info;
    access_log  /dev/stdout;

    location /foo/ {
        proxy_pass         http://serverS;
        proxy_redirect     http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto: https;
    }
```

What can I add to my configuration to avoid the 405 in Chrome?

Comment: Post your answer as an answer please, not in the question.

Comment: Just accept an answer instead of changing your title to say it's solved.

Comment: @JoshLee Added as answer, thanks

Comment: @csmckelvey I've just add an answer an I've accept it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been comparing request between Firefox and Chrome and there is a difference in the Chrome side, in request Chrome add an "Origin" parameter in the header request that is making the error.

So in my nginx.conf I've added the parameter to avoid it under location/

```
proxy_set_header Origin "";
```

So my location configuration block now is:

```
location /foo/ {
    proxy_set_header Origin "";
    proxy_pass         http://serverS;
    proxy_redirect     http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto: https;
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this was happening. Just added the replace and put/delete started to work again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation online for whitelisting HTTP methods can be found [here](https://bjornjohansen.no/restrict-allowed-http-methods-in-nginx)

This works for me:

```
add_header Allow "GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE" always;

if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT|DELETE)$ ) {
   return 405;
}
```

..and obviously, make sure you check the config `nginx -t` and reload config `nginx -s reload` before testing changes

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Indeed there is a problem with header but I think that is not something that Nginx is blocking because when I request from a Firefox explorer everything works fine. It only fails when the request is from Chrome.